# Redirecting stderr and stdout to a file does not write errors when using with statements in Python

Tags: python, stderr, with-statement

I have a program that redirects output and errors to a log file so I can view it when it runs automatically. It worked fine until I switched from using the `open()` and `close()` methods to using a `with` statement.

My original was:

```
import sys
log = open("log.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
sys.stdout = sys.stderr = log
print("hello world")
print(1 / 0)
print("goodbye world")
log.close()
```

And it outputted what I expected:

```
hello world
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(1 / 0)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

But when I changed it to:

```
import sys
with open("log.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as log:
    sys.stdout = sys.stderr = log
    print("hello world")
    print(1 / 0)
    print("goodbye world")
```

The file only shows:

```
hello world
```

I'm not familiar with the differences between the two methods (besides that the second makes it a bit easier to read) so my question is: why does the `with` statement fail to log the error and is there a way to log the errors while keeping the `with` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the `with` statement closes the resource before it can write the error output, due to the occurrence of an exception.
Take a look at it in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with).

> The following code:

```py
with EXPRESSION as TARGET:
    SUITE
```

> is semantically equivalent to:

```py
manager = (EXPRESSION)
enter = type(manager).__enter__
exit = type(manager).__exit__
value = enter(manager)
hit_except = False

try:
    TARGET = value
    SUITE
except:
    hit_except = True
    if not exit(manager, *sys.exc_info()):
        raise
finally:
    if not hit_except:
        exit(manager, None, None, None)
```

The reason the first case handles the exception, is because the resource is closed when python exits, not because of the close statement.

Comment: So considering this, would the only option be to go with the first case then?

Comment: Yes, the first case is the only case where the stderr is written to the file.